# Color.ToArgb relation between 5046311 and 14221235?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

the form backcolor is 14221235 , but when i set the customcolor in colordialog to equal the form backcolor, it sets it to 5046311 !!! what is the problem?

this is how i am getting the background color:

```
get_background = Str(Abs(Form1.BackColor.ToArgb))
```

the reason i am turning it into a string is because i will feed it into a string which has "32498239, 234234234, 23423234, 32234432432, 423324234"

then i take this string and put it in customcolors like this. btw this piece of code works fine:

```
Dim numberStrings = My.Settings.mytext1.Split(","c).Select(Function(x) x.Trim())
ColorDialog1.CustomColors = numberStrings.Select(Function(x) CInt(x)).ToArray()
```

a user below mentioned that toargb takes into account the opacity. this is an excellent point indeed, and i want to clarify that i DO NOT need the opacity. how would i do toargb without taking into opacity?

Comment: Are you using the correct format (hexadecimal, decimal, etc.)?

Comment: mcandre - can you help me with that. i dont know what you mean

Comment: Is the result correct before applying `Abs()` and `Str()`?  Also, by what method did you determine the "correct" color to be 14221235 if `.ToArgb()` is returning 5046311?

Comment: no result is not correct before appying those

Comment: @Votey: I'll bet that's it - a non-zero alpha component can make ToArgb a negative number, which the ABS would then alter.

Comment: musi - im sorry i do not understand can you please explain

Comment: @avrohom: can you write your code so that you don't ever call .ToArgb()? When I do GDI+ code, I either always work with the Color type, or else I work with the R, G and B components separately.

Comment: Also, just try taking the Abs() call out of your code. There's no reason to do that anyway.

Comment: thank you very much for these suggestions. unfortunately i dont think i can take out toargb because it is so fundamental. is there anything i can do to fix this slight problem

Comment: I just looked at your code, and I think you just need to remove the Abs() function to get it to work.

Comment: What do you mean by "fundamental"?  The only time that I *ever* had to use integral representations was when doing some vb6 interop.  I don't see any reason to do things this way from the code you have posted.

Comment: Because of the alpha component, some colors will be negative when converter to an int, so calling Abs() will necessarily change the color.

Comment: You do know that the Color struct has GetBrightness and GetSaturation methods, right?

Comment: Ed - i am sorry i am a noob, can you suggest practically and specifically what needs to be done? i am going to try to remove abs right now

Comment: musi - i tried to remove the abs. it did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is what you want

```
Microsoft.VisualBasic.RGB(Me.BackColor.R, Me.BackColor.G, Me.BackColor.B).ToString
```

Comment: welcome... and thanks for the *3 reputation, next time keep it in one question :-)

Comment: Why the double posted answer? And why use a language-dependent function like RGB?

Comment: @Adam, it was 3 questions, seem to be merged into 1 now, deleted my other one and for the RGB, you can use visualbasic namespace in c# too

Comment: @Adam what would be the "generic" one? color.fromargb? it doesn't convert well into int

Answer (score 2):

The 32-bit result from .ToArgb() contains not just the three visible color components (red, green and blue) but also the alpha component, which is essentially opacity.  This is a pure guess on my part, but I think the ColorDialog is just used for picking RGB values, so when you set the color to the form's BackColor, the dialog just ignores the alpha component (or sets it to zero), which is why you end up getting a different number from the .ToArgb() method.

Note: this is just speculation on my part.  It would help if you posted a code sample that demonstrates the specific problem.

Comment: this could be true. so if this is indeed the case, how do i make it work?

Comment: not sure, in both numbers mentioned in the title the alpha is 00

Comment: @avrohom: I don't fully understand what your actual problem is, i.e. what isn't working. Your form's BackColor property is of the type Color, which makes the RGB components available as separate properties (e.g. form1.BackColor.R, form1.BackColor.G and form1.BackColor.B). There is a constructor for the Color type that takes R, G, and B values - try using the RGB values from the form's BackColor property to create a new Color object, and use this new Color object for your ColorDialog. This will remove the alpha component from the whole deal. Maybe that will fix whatever your problem is.

Comment: @Kip: I think you're right, so I dunno. I'm really not sure what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand the question.  You want to set the custom color dialog CustomColor property to (the form's backcolor) r + g + b components?  Not sure why you would do that, you can always just get the form's backcolor, set the Alpha value to 255 and then set the result to the CustomColor property:

```
Color c = Color.FromArgb( 255, form1.BackColor );
myColorDlg.CustomColor = c;
```

Comment: this is not working unfortunately, i actually need to set a string equal to the color for example: get_background = Str(Abs(Form1.BackColor.ToArgb))

Answer (score 1):

Or just use form1.BackColor.ToArgb() & 0xFFFFFF (if you want the integer value).

Comment: this one is not working, it makes it equal something like this -2342340xFFFFFF

Comment: This would set the alpha component to 0.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking for ARGB (A = Alpha) then you are asking for the opacity information.  Instead you could use the `R`, `G`, `B` Properties of Color Independently.

Comment: how would i set one of the custom colors in colordialog to have the same rgb?>

Comment: you can construct an int with the correct byte ordering (AARRGGBB) and just falsify the AA value with 255.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Color.FromArgb(255, me.BackColor).ToArgb()` in order to get the ARGB value of the same color with 100% opacity.

Comment: Error 1 Value of type 'Integer' cannot be converted to 'System.Drawing.Color'.

Comment: You interpreted his answer too literally, for your needs you don't need the tailing .ToArgb(), drop it and you will be returned a color object and it should work for you.

Comment: i tried just this and it didnt work Color.FromArgb(255, me.BackColor.ToArgb())

Comment: @avrohom, That was a typo. ToArgb() should not be called on me.BackColor in this scenario.

Comment: @Adam: your top-voted question is most ironic, in this case. :)

Answer (score 0):

To highlight how to pass the same colour (Using Fredou's answer) from a colorDialog to set a pie chart segment colour, one which is a .Net embedded chart and the other an Excel chart:

```
embchartPie.Series(0).Points(Index).Color = ColorDialog1.Color
With ColorDialog1.Color
    xl_Pie_Chart.SeriesCollection(1).points(Index + 1).format.fill.forecolor.rgb = RGB(.R, .G, .B).ToString
End With
```